# What is this green, leafy, plant found in Austin Texas called?

Tags: identification, transplanting

This plant came with the house and I want to move it, but before I do I'd like to research it. Does anyone know what this plant is called? It's in Austin, Texas.

[image: Plant]

Comment: What's the location? Knowing that would greatly narrow down the possibilities. Also, have you seen any flowers from it by chance?

Comment: No flowers just green spears basically.Kinda soft and limp. Not thick and sturdy. It's in Austin TX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's some form of Yucca. I moved it from the front to the back and I can report it is still alive and looking very nice.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Spanish bayonet, Yucca aloifolia, or Yucca elephantipes. The first has thorns on the end of the leaves, the second one doesn't - but both usually make a woody stem, so this one's either been cut down, either deliberately or by winter, or its not a Yucca. Leaves look a little too stiff to be one of the Phormium cookanium varieties.

Comment: Most Yuccas seem to have a waxy gray cast to their leaves though...

Comment: Not Yucca elephantipes, that's just green and shiny...

Comment: I think yucca is thicker and stiffer on the leaves. These are thin. Picture might be misleading but it's not sharp or anything.

Comment: @Daniel - close up might help, but there are versions of Yucca with leaves that aren't rigid and thick. No threads hanging from the sides of the leaves anywhere, are there?

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like something in the [Dracaena](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dracaena_(plant)) genus, though I'm not sure specifically which species.

Comment: The leaves look just a little to long and thin to be Dracaena Deremensis, though it might fit.

Comment: If it turns into that, i'm in trouble.

Comment: Why? It's a common enough houseplant, but probably wouldn't do that well outdoors in direct sun.